# Laravel DB Query Using Select and Count together

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to use count and sum together on DB Query not sure how to go about it. I've tried several combinations but keep getting an error. I know I can just use a raw query but would like to learn how to use it correctly

Working:

```
DB::select('SELECT count(*) AS order_count, sum(total_including_vat) 
    AS orders_total FROM orders WHERE user_id =' .$userProfile->id);
```

Not Working

```
DB::table('orders')->where('user_id', '=', $userProfile->id)->count()->Sum();
```

Comment: Try with DB::table('orders')->where('user_id', $userProfile->id)->count();

Answer (score 1):

count same as [aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#aggregates) returns single value so

```php
// you try to call method sum on number and it fails
DB::table('orders')->where('user_id', $userProfile->id)->count()->sum();
```

you can make two requests to get `sum` and `count` but its not a good idea, or get data in [collection and let it do](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#available-methods) the [math](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-sum)

```php
// not a good idea
//$count = DB::table('orders')->where('user_id', $userProfile->id)->count();
//$sum = DB::table('orders')->where('user_id', $userProfile->id)->sum('total_including_vat');

//collection way
$orders = DB::table('orders')
  ->where('user_id',$userPorfile->id)
  ->get(['id', 'total_including_vat']);
$result = [
  'order_count' => $orders->count(),
  'orders_total' => $orders->sum('total_including_vat')
];
```

or the same result as for your working example with mix [raw expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#raw-expressions)

```php
$result = DB::table('orders')
  ->where('user_id', $userProfile->id)
  ->selectRaw('count(1) as order_count, sum(total_including_vat) as orders_total')
  ->first();
```